# How to modify the height of the statusbar in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone, statusbar

How do I modify the height, background, margin and padding of the statusbar in [Codename one](https://www.codenameone.com)?

It looks very bad.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't base the look of the statusbar on simulator output, this will be different from the looks on real devices.

If you want to style the statusbar, modify UIIDs **StatusBar** and **StatusBarSideMenu** to your desire.

Answer (score 2):

As Diamond said, you should modify UIIDs StatusBar and StatusBarSideMenu.
The way to do that is the following:

1. Open theme.res file
2. Find the theme under Themes
3. Open the UIID you want to change, if it is not present, click Add.
4. Type the name of the UIID
5. Change the style however you wish

Then call .setUIID() method on the component on which you want to do that. Note that components by default get UIID, for example Label has UIID "Label" and so on, so you won't need to call setUIID.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I was assuming he should already know how to do that or ask if he doesn't.